# Sql renaming a header in the result set when using stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that I need to synchronize itemnumbers between our ERP and our Pim-system.

```
 SELECT ISSS.No_ Value, 
    [Substitute No_]= STUFF(
                            (SELECT ';' + [Substitute No_] From [Company-Europe B_V_$Item Substitution]  
                                WHERE [Relation Type] = 0 AND No_= ISSS.No_  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1, ''
                            )   FROM [Company-Europe B_V_$Item Substitution] as ISSS Where [Relation Type] = 0
     group by No_ Order by NO_ asc
```

The results I get are as follows:

```
Value|Substitute No_
1      2;3
4      5
```

However I order to synchronise the data my Substitute No_ needs a different name.
where can I place that result without breaking the querie

Comment: Hint:  ` [Substitute No_]= STUFF(`

Comment: Is `[Company-Europe B_V_$Item Substitution]` really the name of your table?! O.o Whitespace, and special characters in an object's name is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you can indent correctly you can spot where you give alias to your column.

```
SELECT 
    ISSS.No_ Value, 
    [Substitute No_] = STUFF(       -- Here!!!
        (
            SELECT 
                ';' + [Substitute No_] 
            From 
                [Company-Europe B_V_$Item Substitution]  
            WHERE 
                [Relation Type] = 0 AND 
                No_= ISSS.No_  
            FOR XML 
                PATH ('')
        ),
        1,1, '')   
FROM 
    [Company-Europe B_V_$Item Substitution] as ISSS 
Where 
    [Relation Type] = 0
group by 
    No_ 
Order by 
    NO_ asc
```